# Would fuel quantity indications be affected by extended flight at nonzero bank angles?

Tags: flight-instruments, fuel-tanks, fuel-systems

If flying with a 20kt crosswind requiring yaw input as well as roll input to maintain course, would the fuel indicators show different loads depending on the roll angle of the aircraft (in this case, an MH-53e)

Clarification: With a left bank angle of 15-20 degrees would it appear that the right side fuel cells were using fuel faster with a quantitative fuel quantity system?

Thank you sir. That is a better way of saying it.

Comment: Isn't the plane still flying straight and level even with a crosswind, even though course and heading are different?

Comment: It depends, what indication are you looking at? I'm guessing on the MH-53 it is a fuel totalizer, not an actual gauge. If it were a physical gauge it may change, but more expensive military/commercial aircraft use totalizers.

Comment: Crosswind requires a 20deg bank angle with yaw input to fly along a predetermined course. It's pretty windy and this is an actual pilot reported issue.

Comment: 4 tanks and it is a totalizer system so each probe covers the tanks from top to bottom and you can transfer to and from all tanks

Comment: Where did you get the idea that flying a predetermined course in a crosswind requires a constant nonzero bank angle?

Comment: While towing mine countermeasure gear pilots must fly a predetermined track and pilot reported having to fly at the angle

Comment: @Steve compensation for the wind needs yaw normally

Comment: @Derek You should learn the difference between _crab_ (putting your nose into the crosswind) and _side slip_ (lowering your wing into the crosswind). The second thing is probably never used in steady flight, it's usually used only in final moments of a crosswind landing and in first moments of a crosswind take-off.

Comment: I do actually know the difference.  The aircraft was towing minesweeping gear and required both yaw and roll inputs to follow the track that was being cleared.  The tracks are plotted by gps coordinates. This is an actual pilot reported issue which I was the primary troubleshooter. We call it crab walking and unless you understand that they are dragging an object through the water while flying under 100 ft which not a normal thing most pilots have done you shouldn't be condescending in your reply yo'

Answer (score 2):

I don't know what fuel quantity indicating system is installed on the MH-53, but most aircraft use a capacitive indicating system. Basically, there are multiple probes spaced throughout the fuel tank(s). During a turn or bank, the fuel will accumulate to one side of the tank, which increases the capacitance on the respective probes on that side of the tank. Meanwhile, the capacitance decreases on the probes that aren't covered as much. Total capacitance of all the probes is then summed and processed. Basically, no matter how the aircraft is oriented, in a properly operating system, there should be no detectable change in fuel quantity.

Comment: It is capacitance based but has a single probe per cell and bags out around 24k pounds split between 4 cells

Comment: Each cell has its own indicator plus a total just to clarify

Comment: Generally speaking, a capacitance based system will be designed so that all but the most extreme flight characteristics are accounted for. My guess is that there would be very little or zero change. That said, it's possible there is something in the flight manual or maintenance manual about extreme flight characteristics and the fuel qty reading.

Comment: As the overall load decreases the appearance of a miscompare increases. Even though fuel is being used from each tank equally the stationary fuel probes show more fuel on the wing down side.

Comment: Are you sure fuel is being used from each tank equally as the level decreases and these maneuvers are performed?

Comment: @Frank I'd add that in violent maneuvers / turbulences, you simply wouldn't rely on the fuel readings for a while if they started behaving weirdly.

Comment: @yo' I'm thinking of this from a strict maintenance standpoint, as I'm not a pilot. I am presuming these maneuvers to be for an extended period of time rather than a quick maneuver. I would agree that in extreme maneuvering, it is possible for there to be some unreliability. That said, if a maneuver can be held for a long period of time, it's not so abnormal is it?